# Refactoring CSS to reduce adjoining classes

Tags: css

Is there a way of writing CSS to reduce the file size of a style sheet containing lots of adjoining classes. Example...

```
body .elementor-2 .elementor-element.elementor-element-949d9dd .elementor-widget-spacer,
body .elementor-2 .elementor-element.elementor-element-427933f .elementor-widget-spacer,
body .elementor-2 .elementor-element.elementor-element-cb8ce37 .elementor-widget-spacer {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No, there really isn't. Nesting is coming somewhere in the future, but for now, there isn't. You could go for precompilers if its a dev thing, but I don't think you'll be able to minimise this a lot if you need to target those classes in that order.

Comment: Use more specific selectors or a CSS minifier.

Answer (score 0):

hey Use :is selector to reduce the code please check. to learn more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/is/)

```css
body .elementor-2 .elementor-element:is(.elementor-element-949d9dd, .elementor-element-427933f, .elementor-element-cb8ce37  ) .elementor-widget-spacer  {
margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-2">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-949d9dd ">
    <div class="elementor-widget-spacer">spacer</div>      
  </div>      
</div>
<div class="elementor-2">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-427933f">
    <div class="elementor-widget-spacer">spacer</div>      
  </div>      
</div>
<div class="elementor-2">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-cb8ce37 ">
    <div class="elementor-widget-spacer">spacer</div>      
  </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the widget spacer in a different position every single widget makes those classes with the different ids. So you can't reduce the classes.

So if you need not write all the classes on the CSS file.

Use this CSS.

```
body .elementor-widget-spacer {
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

or

```
body .elementor-widget-spacer {
   margin: 0;
}
```

It works with all of the spacer widgets on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using elementor.you don't need to do it with custom CSS. Elementor has a dedicated control for this. edit the column, select the layout tab to find widget space, and make it 0. Inside the column, your widget gap will be 0.
[Before Doing 0](https://prnt.sc/ai-GYte88Dnj)

[After Doing 0](https://prnt.sc/6lyPFGKOtkM1)

Or
you are not using Elementor you can go with :is().To learn more about it follow the article [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/is/)